# What's the danger of adding to a list in one thread and removing from another without locking it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

### Preamble

I know that the `List` is not thread-safe and am aware of the existence of concurrent collections such as `ConcurrentBag`, `ConcurrentQueue`, etc., and know how to use locks, to some extent. I just want to know what's the danger(s) would be if I do such a thing.

### Question

Say, if I have 2 threads running concurrently, one adding value to a `List`, the other removing elements from the same `List`, what's the danger(s) would be?

I know that the danger might be critical if I add elements in both threads since the `List` internally resizing and reindexing the collection, and the "race" is going to corrupt that, but `Add` and `Remove` are essentially opposite operations, I don't see there is any "conflict" in it.

I also know that `Remove` internally resizing and re-indexing the collection too, but to be honest I don't know how they internally work, I don't really know if "2 opposite operations will still corrupt the data". If yes, in what way? (Except for the obvious danger of "there might be nothing to be removed because the element is not being added yet").

Comment: It is irrelevant how they work internally. In fact the implementation can change depending on platform, environment, and even .Net version. The point is it is not thread safe. This should be enough for you. As for implementation details: adding and removing on list typically involves internal pointer incrementing and decrementing. These operations are not generally atomic. Moreover are not visible outside the thread if not volatile (which is common situation). This can lead to weird issues like one thread thinking it needs resize because he never saw the other thread removing anything.

Comment: And whatever special use case might be thread safe now, it is not guaranteed to be in the future.

Comment: The only thing you can do to an object from two threads at the same time are _atomic_ operations (like setting or reading an integer).  When you add something to a collection or remove something from you are accessing the internal state of the collection (for example, adding an object to an internal array or inserting it into a linked list, and updating the count).  Even a simple "read-modify-write" operation (like reading an integer and incrementing it) cannot be done in a thread safe fashion without some synchronization or interlocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have 2 threads running concurrently, one adding value to a List, the other removing elements from the same List, what's the danger(s) would be?

The most likely faults would be that added values are lost, or that removed values are not actually removed. There can also be exceptions since the list might get into an invalid state.

While add and remove could be considered opposite operations, they are not *atomic*, meaning they will do multiple things, and will not work correctly if something changes in the middle of the operation. Contrast with `Interlocked.Increment` & `Interlocked.Decrement` that *are* atomic, so can safely be used from multiple threads.

In the end the only thing you should be concerned about is if it is documented as threadsafe or not. If it is thread safe you can just use it. If it is not you need to use locks whenever it is used from multiple threads. The correct behavior of the program is much more important than minor things like the performance impact of locks. If correct behavior is not required you can gain an near infinite speedup by just replacing your whole program with `return 0;`

There is one possible exception, concurrently reading memory is safe, so if you are sure the method do not mutate the object in any way it could be used concurrently without any locking. `List<T>` [explicitly documents that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0#thread-safety) concurrent reads are safe.

Comment: it's also plausible it could scramble the elements after the removal point; duplicate some; delete some; or just outright crash

Comment: Why didn’t I ever think to replace my whole program with “return 0;”?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to demonstrate that this use of `List<T>` will cause problems.

Consider the following program ([also on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oVQsLT)):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new();
        Task.Run(() => addItems(list));
        Task.Run(() => removeItems(list));

        Console.WriteLine("Started. Press <return> to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void addItems(List<int> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; ++i)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        Volatile.Write(ref finished, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished writing items");
    }

    static void removeItems(List<int> list)
    {
        int n = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                ++n;
                list.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                bool done = Volatile.Read(ref finished);

                if (done)
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Finished reading {n} items");
    }

    static bool finished;
}
```

This starts two threads: One which writes 100K items to a list, and another that reads the items from that list.

The `finished` field is just there to indicate that the `addItems()` task has completed adding items.

The `readItems()` task counts the number of items that it's read from the list. Clearly, the resulting number should equal the number of items added to the list.

However, you'll find that it *sometimes* reads more items than were written, because the multithreaded access to the list has caused a bug.
(You may have to run it several times to see this problem.)

The moral of this story is DON'T DO THAT!

---

Just as a sidenote, if you add a lock around the list access, it will work correctly and print the correct number of items:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new();
        Task.Run(() => addItems(list));
        Task.Run(() => removeItems(list));

        Console.WriteLine("Started. Press <return> to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void addItems(List<int> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; ++i)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
        }

        Volatile.Write(ref finished, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished writing items");
    }

    static void removeItems(List<int> list)
    {
        int n = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    ++n;
                    list.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool done = Volatile.Read(ref finished);

                    if (done)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Finished reading {n} items");
    }

    static object locker = new();

    static bool finished;
}
```